Trouble compiling and running an OpenCV project with CUDA in Visual Studio, net.forward();
I'm encountering issues while compiling and running my OpenCV project with CUDA in Visual Studio. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 in windows 11 and have configured OpenCV 4.8.0 with CUDA 12.1 and CUDNN 8.9.3 . Despite following the setup instructions, I'm receiving an error during compilation/execution. The error message I'm encountering is Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD4697DF51 (cudnn64_8.dll) in TestTensorflow.exe: Fatal program exit requested., and it occurs at outputs = net.forward() ;. I've verified my CUDA installation and ensured that the necessary environment variables and paths are correctly set up. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/utils/logger.hpp>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include<opencv2/dnn/all_layers.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace dnn;

const float INPUT_WIDTH = 640.0;
const float INPUT_HEIGHT = 640.0;

std::vector<std::string> load_class_list()
{
    vector<string> class_names;
    ifstream ifs(string("namesPpe.txt").c_str()); 
    string line;
   
        while (getline(ifs, line))
        {
            cout<<line <<endl;
            class_names.push_back(line);
        }
        return class_names;
    // Load in all the classes from the file
}


cv::dnn::Net load_net() {
    auto net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX("yolov8x.onnx");

    if (cv::cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()) {
        cout << "cuda esta disponible";
        net.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CUDA);
        net.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_CUDA);
        //net.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CUDA);
    }
    else {
        cout << "cuda NO esta disponible";
    }
    return net;
}
//************************************************************************************************************************
Mat pre_process(Mat& input_image, Net& net)
{
    //Convert to blob.
    Mat blob = blobFromImage(input_image, 1.0, Size(INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT), Scalar(104.0, 117.0, 123.0), true, false);;
    net.setInput(blob);
    Mat outputs;
    outputs = net.forward();
    return outputs;
}

int main() {
    //imprimimos y mostramos las classes


    std::vector<string> class_names = load_class_list();
    cv::dnn::Net net = load_net();
    cv::Mat input_image = cv::imread("image.jpg");
    cv::Mat outputs = pre_process(input_image, net);
    return 0;
}


Have you included the specified DLL in your executable folder? Just try to include the DLL the folder where your executable will be by literally copying/pasting the DLL there to see what happens.

When i built opencv in cmake i used opencv_world,so i  have opencv_world480.dll and opencv_world480.lib. they are in other folder so i included the path in C++/General/Additional Include Directories, also opencv_world480.lib in Linker/inputs and its path in library directories , still the same error

i'm sorry i  found the  cudnn64_8.dll and cudnn64_8.lib in the CUDA folder, i copied de .dll  and .lib in the exectuable folder, it recognized de cudnn64_8.lib in (Linker/inputs) but still the same error. i really apreciate your time, there is something else i could do?

I think there may be something wrong with that net.forward() call, from the documentation it seems like there should be at least one argument: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d30/classcv_1_1dnn_1_1Net.html#a98ed94cb6ef7063d3697259566da310b

I found the problem, first  y changed and Mat outputs; and net.forward(); for vector<Mat> outputs; net.forward(outputs, net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()); so my functions return a vector<Mat>, then there was a message  in console could not locate zlibwapi.dll. Please make sure it is in your library path , I used this
Forum Could not locate zlibwapi.dll. Please make sure it is in your library path to solved that problem.
corrected function:
vector<Mat> pre_process(Mat& input_image, Net& net)
{
    //Convert to blob.
    Mat blob = blobFromImage(input_image, 1.0, Size(INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT), Scalar(104.0, 117.0, 123.0), true, false);;
    net.setInput(blob);
    vector<Mat> outputs;
    net.forward(outputs, net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames());
    //outputs = net.forward();
    return outputs;
}

